# Save purchase state/button state in-app billing android

Tags: android, google-play, in-app

How to save button state of in-app billing?

i.e, For example, if a person buys a product using Google in-app billing, The next time he opens the application the button must be in unlocked state. I followed few tutorials and am successful in adding button and making purchase but the button remains active only for one time i.e, when user leaves the app he/she must purchase once again which isn't proper in-app billing.

Comment: have you done any research regarding your need?

Answer (score 1):

Just save the buying state in SharedPreferences when it was successful.

```
private Boolean isUpgrade(Context context) 
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);        
    return prefs.getBoolean("upgrade", false);
}

private void setUpgrade(Context context, Boolean value) 
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putBoolean("upgrade", value);        
    edit.commit();
}
```

Comment: / ashatte Thanks for the code.i will try it and let you know ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

First, call the following method to obtain shared preferences in your application:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.your.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To write/update a preference value:

```
prefs.edit().putBoolean("buyState", true).commit();
```

To read a preference value:

```
prefs.getBoolean("buyState", false);
```

Note that *false* is a default value to be returned if there is no value stored in preferences for *buyState*.